# C# HTTP GET always trying to CONNECT first

Tags: c#, http

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var request = await client.GetAsync("https://www.somerandomsite.com");
string response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

This piece of code (and all other GET snippets found around) always fires a HTTP CONNECT (to the address specified) first and only then (as I understand, through the tunnel) fires the simple GET request I want to make.

As far as I know, what happens here is my code asks somerandomsite.com to act as a proxy between the code and the site itself... which sounds a little nonsense. Or I misunderstood the CONNECT method terribly.

Why does it happen? Why cannot it just directly GET?

---

It happens regardless of the URI requested.

Passing `var handler = new HttpClientHandler() {UseProxy = false};` to the client doesn't change a thing.

Comment: What do you mean it's sending an HTTP CONNECT? Where are you seeing that? And what makes you think it's acting as a proxy?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/CONNECT

Comment: @mason I see it in Fiddler. I think it's acting as a proxy because proxying is, as far as I read around, the purpose of the CONNECT method.
(... or does it simply mean a TCP socket is opened and kept alive for improved performance, as opposed to full statelessness? Articles about CONNECT clearly state it's about proxying)

Comment: Either the site you're attempting to access is a proxy, or you have a proxy between you and that site (such as a corporate firewall), and wants you to CONNECT first to open the TLS tunnel.

Comment: @Amy It CONNECTs always, regardless of the address. There is no proxy I think, I'm just in my private network. From the browser I can just GET. Also passing a HttpClientHandler with `UseProxy = false` to HttpClient yields the same result.

Comment: All `https` connections begin with a `CONNECT`, as far as I am aware.  It's what allows the `SSL` tunnel to operate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Sam Axe, HTTP CONNECT is a necessary part of initializing all TLS connections.